# is there a way through which WebView can open pdf by clicking on a link which is inside the loaded webpage URL?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

[enter image description here][1]I want to open a `pdf` in `WebView`, not by directly passing the pdf URL. This means there is a URL that opens in `WebView` and when that page opens in WebView it contains a link that opens `pdf`.

How can I open that `pdf` in `WebView`?
For example:
This is the screenshot of webpage loaded in WebView (Open the below image).
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z71pr.png

In side this image their is a option of view in Action row. So How to open that pdf which is coming from a URL loaded in WebView?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can open any pdf on internet using google drive link. For example, if your pdf url is:

```
String pdf = "https://mywebsite/mypdf.pdf"
```

Just embed this link in following google drive link:

```
String gDrive = "http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url="
```

So now your URL is: "http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=https://mywebsite/mypdf.pdf"

and open this in your webview. Remember to include this URL in your WebViewClient if you are filtering the urls to open in app or chrome.

[Edit]

To open url after taping on the link, you need to create a WebView Client which overrides each url like this:

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    //link opener
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.endsWith(".pdf") )
        {
            //create another webview activity and load the url as mentioned above so that it does not keeps on reloading
           myWebView.load(gDrive);
           
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

and set this webview client as:

```
myWebview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient())
```

or if you want to load in the same activity/fragment you can modify the condition as:

```
if(url.endsWith(".pdf") && !url.contains("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url="))
```

and do the same. Hope this is what you want to do.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it's not the way I am looking for. Actually the link of pdf is inside the Url which will be loaded in WebView.

Comment: Can you send an example?

Comment: Checkout my question again, I have uploaded a example.

Comment: I have edited my answer according to it. Hope this is what you are looking for.